# Testing differences of multiple means and variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

Does ANOVA tests the pairwise difference of multiple means at once, or is there any method to test the pairwise difference of multiple means or variances at once?

Comment: Did you hear about the multiple comparison problem? Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ANOVA doesn't test the pairwise differences. The F statistic doesn't tell you anything other than there is a difference. You'll need multiple comparison procedures, and there're many of them.